# POST file with bash CGI

Tags: html, bash, post, file-upload, cgi

I'm trying to upload a file (about 30kb in this case). I'm using a bash CGI at the receiving end. So far I would just like to see the contents of the file.

Receiving end:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Content-Type: text/plain"
echo

read FILE
echo "$FILE"
```

Sender form:

```
<form class="fileup_form" method="post" action="dds_fileup.cgi" enctype="multipart/form-data">                                          
   <input type="submit" />                                              
   <input type="file" name="file" />                                    
</form>
```

At the moment I get this output:

```
-----------------------------11054464466732224131260756282
```

which is definitely not the full 30kb.

**Why can't I see the full contents of the POSTed file?**

Comment: Read only "reads" till the first new line by default.  For an example See: http://git.busybox.net/busybox/tree/networking/httpd_post_upload.txt

Answer (score 1):

'read' only reads one line. Try this instead:

```
FILE=`cat`
echo $FILE
```

Comment: It might be better to size limit the upload using: FILE="$(cat | dd count=1 bs=1M)" ...or any size that you think is good for you.